# Issue in accessing asp.net application aspx pages on IIS 7.5 with machine name/IP url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

I **have re written a vb.net framework 2.0 application to c#** .net framework 4.0.

I have hosted my new asp.net application on **IIS 7.5**. The application is accessible once I hit the url as http://localhost/appname from internet explorer **8.0**. But the **issue comes when I use the computer name or IP address in place of localhost in url.** 
The **User Interface of few **aspx pages** are getting distorted with one page displaying with no controls**. Its just a white page appearing.

On the other hand I have the same application written in vb.net with framework 2.0. . This application is behaving fine with both way of accessing ( localhost or with machine/IP name) .

Please help regarding the hosting and accessing the new c# rewritten application??

Regards,
Joshi_007

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have subfolders in your site holding your styles etc.. are your controls user controls in a subfolder?

ensure your site's subfolders have location entries in your config...

```
<location path="content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
 <location path="resources">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```